# How to edit open-delay in Element UI collapsed horizontal menu

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

I find it a little annoying when you hover over the menu items fast in a collapsed horizontal menu. So I wanted to edit the seconds where it shows the tooltop.

The tooltip component of ELement UI have an attribute that let us edit the open-delay of the tooltip.

How do we do this in the collapsed horizontal menu, where it shows the title of the menu item?

[screenshot](http://prntscr.com/m4pcxp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit the open-delay in element UI simlply change the open-delay attribute, bind the value you want in milliseconds as desired i.e for one second it should be 1000. like this:

```
<el-tooltip content="Top center" :open-delay="1000" placement="top">
<el-button>Dark</el-button>
</el-tooltip>
```

If you need to reduce the duration use a smaller number and vice versa.

see docs [Element UI docs](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/tooltip)

For your case wrap the menu-item element with a tooltip and configure the open-delay as required example:

```
<el-tooltip class="item" effect="dark" :open-delay="1000" 
content="Right Center prompts info" placement="right">
<el-menu-item index="2">
<i class="el-icon-menu"></i>
<span  >Navigator Two</span>
</el-menu-item>
</el-tooltip>
```

[see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6fq9wzu/14/)

Comment: Hi, please note that this is my question "How do we do this in the collapsed horizontal menu, where it shows the title of the menu item?". Thanks..

Comment: @japhfortin I have updated my answer, see fiddle the second menu-item

Comment: Great idea! @Lupyana :) I just needed to add something to suit my needs..

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way because the component does not contemplate it. So @Lupyana Mbembati solution works:

```
<el-tooltip effect="dark" placement="right" content="About" :open-delay="400">
    <el-menu-item :index="localePath('index')">
        <i class="el-icon-user"></i>
    </el-menu-item>
</el-tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Lupyana's answer, I just needed to add something for it to accommodate what I really want to happen.

Instead of letting element-ui do the automatic conversion of tooltip when the menu is collapsed. All we have to do is to do it manually by just disabling the tooltip when it is not collapsed so it doesn't show up when the menu is expanded.

from:

```
<el-menu-item index="/">
    <span slot="title">Home</span>
</el-menu-item>
```

to:

```
<el-tooltip effect="dark" :open-delay="300" content="Home" placement="right" :disabled="!is_collapse">
    <el-menu-item index="/">
        <span>Home</span>
    </el-menu-item>
</el-tooltip>
```